# Angular 2 custom event not caught by template

Tags: javascript, events, typescript, angular

I'm facing a problem involving custom events in Angular 2.

I need to throw a cusotm event after clicking on a particular DOM element. I am able to emit the event but it looks like this event is not caught by the template which should be listening. Here my code:

***SidebarContent.ts***:

```
import {EventEmitter, Component, DynamicComponentLoader, 
ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Output} from 'angular2/core';



@Component({
    selector: 'ico-sidebar-content'
    , templateUrl: 'App/Pages/Filters/SidebarContent/SidebarContent.html'

})

export class SidebarContent {
    @Output('open') open = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    public emitEvent() {
        console.log("clicked!");
        this.open.emit(null);
        console.log("maybe emitted");
    }
}
```

the `emitEvent()` function is called when I click on the following element in `SidebarContent.html`:

```
<li (click)="emitEvent()" *ngFor="#value of filter.values"><a><i
                                class="fa {{value.faIconClass}}"></i>{{value.name}}</a></li>
```

Now, the class that is supposed to catch the event is in ***FilterTiles.ts***:

```
import {Component,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ico-filter-tiles'
    , templateUrl: 'App/Pages/Filters/Components/FilterTiles/FilterTiles.html'
})


export class FilterTiles {
    public tiles = [{
            title: 'Sesso',
            faIconClass: 'fa-users',
            values: [
                'griffin'
                , 'simpson'
            ]
        }];

    public open(){
        console.log('Got it!'); 
    }
}
```

finally `FilterTiles.html` (the template where I try to bind the event to the `open()` function above):

```
<h1 (open)="open()" (click)="open()">heeee</h1>
<div *ngFor="#tile of tiles" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="x_panel ico_filter_tiles">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="x_title">
                <i class="fa fa-map"></i><span class="panel-title-label">Azienda
                    di residenza</span> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i
                    class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right ico_remove"></i></a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <fieldset>
                                <ul class="ico_filter_ul_select form-control">
                                    <li *ngFor="#value of tile.values"><div class="checkbox">
                                            <label><input type="checkbox">ABCDE</label>
                                        </div></li>
                                </ul>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was not able to find my error, can someone of you please help me?

Thank you ;)

Comment: Your `h1` element is not emitting the `open` output. It must be in another part of your template. Can you post the full template for FilterTiles?

Comment: I posted the full template. What do you mean with " element is not emitting the open output"? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the event can be caught where the `SidebarContent` component is applied. In your case, an element with the name `ico-sidebar-content`:

```
<ico-sidebar-content (open)="doSomething()"></ico-sidebar-content>
```

You defined it on a simple `h1` element which doesn't correspond to the `SidebarContent` component.

**Edit**

If you want to make communicate two components, you can leverage an `EventEmitter` within a shared service.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() {
    this.myEvent = new EventEmitter();
  }
}

@Component({
})
export class SidebarContent {
  constructor(private service:MyService) {
  }

  emitEvent() {
    service.emit('data');
  }
}

@Component({
})
export class BodyContent {
  constructor(private service:MyService) {
  }

  listenEvent() {
    service.subscribe(
      data => {
        // do something with data
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Be careful to define the service provider to make component share the same instance (for example, within the `bootstrap` function).
Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: And what if I want a component to listen to an event emitted by another component? Because here I need to modify my `BodyContent` when the sidebar emits that event. How do I let `BodyContent` to listen to events emitted by `SidebarContent`?

Comment: To do this, you can leverage an EventEmitter within a shared service. I updated my answer...

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is emit an event to the parent component of both of your components and then bind to an input on the other component.  I like Thierry's way better, but I haven't quite got my mind rapped around services yet.  Actually, his answer has helped me understand them quite a bit better.

```
import {Component,EventEmitter,OnChanges} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
selector: 'ico-filter-tiles'
, templateUrl: 'App/Pages/Filters/Components/FilterTiles/FilterTiles.html'
})
inputs:['catchEvent'] // <--- Added this


export class FilterTiles implements OnChanges{ // <--- Added this
public tiles = [{
        title: 'Sesso',
        faIconClass: 'fa-users',
        values: [
            'griffin'
            , 'simpson'
        ]
    }];

public catchEvent; // <--- Added for easier code completion,not needed

ngOnChanges(e){ // <--- Added this, make sure to import OnChanges
    if(e['catchEvent']{
        this.open();
    }
}

public open(){
    console.log('Got it!'); 
}
}
```

Now add this to `<ico-filter-tiles [catchEvent]="someVarToBind" ></ico-filter-tiles>`. Add `someVarToBind` to your parent component and a function like your `open()` in `FilterTiles` to parent compenent.

Example:

```
openFilterTiles(){
    this.someVarToBind = true;
}
```

Then add `<ico-sidebar-content (open)="openFilterTiles()"></ico-sidebar-content>`

If you do it this way, you are basically using your parent component as a mediator.  It might be easier for you to understand this way, but I would suggest trying to learn the `services` way of doing things.

The reason I don't like passing it around is because you end up having a bunch of extra functions/methods in your root component or parent component.